# Pass Javascript variable to HTML button as href

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I have this javascript that fetches a users folderID and gives back a link to that folder.

```
    <script>
        function onSuccess(ID_FOLDER) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        var FolderPathURL = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/"+ID_FOLDER+"";
        div.innerHTML = "<a href='"+FolderPathURL+"' target='_blank'>Link to Folder</a>"
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getFolderIds();
    </script>
```

The html looks like this, and a href link is presented. This works as is right now.

```
<div id="output">Folder URL</div>
```

But i need the link to be a button (a google css blue action button), so when they click the button the link opens.

```
<button class="action">Show Folder</button>
```

Comment: Links are links. Buttons are buttons. If you want a link to look a particular way, apply CSS.

Comment: That's what i though. I need to read the css documentation for https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css i guess

Comment: `div.innerHTML = '<button class="action" onmouseup='window.open("' + FolderPathURL + '" >Open your Folder</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Add this class to the relevant link tags:

```
.button-blue {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d90fe, #4787ed);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4d90fe, #4787ed);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4d90fe, #4787ed);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4d90fe, #4787ed);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #4d90fe, #4787ed);
  border: 1px solid #3079ed;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script>
    function onSuccess(ID_FOLDER) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    var FolderPathURL = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/"+ID_FOLDER+"";
    div.innerHTML = "<a href='"+FolderPathURL+"' target='_blank'><button class="action button-blue">Show Folder</button> </a>"
    }
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getFolderIds();
</script>
```

add css as @Ashwin has suggested

```
.button-blue {
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d90fe, #4787ed);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4d90fe, #4787ed);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4d90fe, #4787ed);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4d90fe, #4787ed);
 background: linear-gradient(top, #4d90fe, #4787ed);
 border: 1px solid #3079ed;
 color: #fff;
 }
```

Comment: I'm trying the suggested edits, but the button isn't showing. There is already a button that i can use from the css "action" which is blue. However don't i need to use "onclick"?

Comment: It's just not working passing a button to the innerHTML div. Isn't there any other way of doing this, this dosen't feel like the right way to do it.

Comment: You can call function on onclick event of existing button , and in that function you can use `window.location=........`  to redirect to same link @John Smith

Comment: Let me know , if window.location works for you or not

Answer (score 0):

As of HTML5, buttons support the formaction attribute. Best of all no javascript or trickery needed.

**Change:**

```
  div.innerHTML = "<a href='"+FolderPathURL+"' target='_blank'><button class="action button-blue">Show Folder</button> </a>"
```

**To:**

```
  div.innerHTML = "<form><button formaction='"+FolderPathURL+"'>Show Folder</button></form>"
```